# How to use orb on a image in CV2?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, orb, opencv3.1

I wish to use ORB (http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d89/tutorial_py_orb.html#gsc.tab=0) on a 28*28 grayscale image (handwritten digits), where each pixel has a number from 0 to 255.

This is the code I used:

```
# image = {load the array of 754 numbers}
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
image = image.reshape(28, 28))
kp = orb.detect(image, None)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F) in cvtColor, file /home/yahya/Documents/_other_downloaded_apps/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 7935
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yahya/Documents/hello.py", line 118, in <module>
    kp = orb.detect(image, None)
cv2.error: /home/yahya/Documents/_other_downloaded_apps/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:7935: error: (-215) depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F in function cvtColor
```

How can I do this and why am I getting this error?

**UPDATE**

I seemed to have solved part of this problem. It turns out that orb accepts float32 numbers (not 64).

Therefore I updated my code as follows:

```
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
image = feature_x[0].reshape(28, 28).astype('float32')
kp = orb.detect(image, None)
```

But now I have the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in ipp_cvtColor, file /home/yahya/Documents/_other_downloaded_apps/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 7456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yahya/Documents/hello.py", line 188, in <module>
    kp = orb.detect(image, None)
cv2.error: /home/yahya/Documents/_other_downloaded_apps/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:7456: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function ipp_cvtColor
```

Comment: how are you creating the image?

Comment: It's an image from the mnist data set: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/index.html. I have not created it my self. It is simply an array of 784 (28*28) numbers between 0-255. Therefore when I reshape it, it makes a 28*28 matrix.

Comment: I added an example image from my data set

Comment: as far as I know ORB only accepts 8-bit grayscale image. I am not sure about the float32 (float32 is a valid opencv image type but I don't think it will work for orb). The error you are getting is because of number of channels in the image isn't 3 or 4. I think opencv check for this if the image is float32f

Answer (score 3):

The image you are trying to load isn't compatible type for the orb. You should convert it first before using it. Also you don't need `reshape` if you are loading it into numpy array

```
orb = cv2.ORB_create()
image = image.astype(np.uint8, copy=False)
kp = orb.detect(image, None)
```

Comment: I do need reshape, else it won't know its a 28*28 image. Also rasies an error. Also thanks for the help!